# PHP Select data between 2 dates

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sir I try the between operator in mysql php but the result or the output is wrong.

```
$currentdate = "05-23-2016";

$startdate = "01-01-1001";

$sql="SELECT * FROM `trial` WHERE Schedule BETWEEN '".$startdate."' AND '".$currentdate."' ";
    $result =mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            echo $row['ID']." - ".$row['Msched'].'-'.$row['Dsched'].'-'.$row['Ysched']."" ;

    }
```

Output
1 - 05-18-2016
4 - 04-28-2005
5 - 01-26-2020

Comment: I am puzzled, too. Please try to describe which result you would have expected instead and/or explain why you think that it is wrong.

Comment: Try it with Y-m-d formatted input dates instead. (2016-05-23)

Comment: Yep, perhaps this might help us: 1. Also add $row['Schedule'] into the echo statement and 2. post the `CREATE TABLE` statement of table `trial` here, such that we can see the data types you are using.

Comment: Is there a correlation between `Schedule` and `Ysched` in your database (i.e. computed columns?)

Comment: Thank you sir and @Don'tPanic i try it and now it is okay i get my output now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `trial` WHERE (Schedule BETWEEN '".$startdate."' AND '".$currentdate."') ";
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help

Answer (score 0):

You also can try:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `trial` WHERE (Schedule >= '".$startdate."' 
  AND Schedule < '".$currentdate."') ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT *FROM table WHERE schedule BETWEEN '".$startdate."' AND '".$enddate."'";
```